Difference of $p^0$ and $E_p$
In QFT when I learn about Feynman-propagator, I see such an expression:
$$
\frac{1}{2E_p}e^{-iE_p(x^0-y^0)}=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_Cdp^0\frac{e^{-ip^0(x^0-y^0)}}{(p^0-E_p)(p^0+E_p)}.
$$
I know that this equation can be derived using Cauchy's integral formula. But I don't understand what it means by $p^0$ and $E_p$? So far I know, $p^0$ is the 0-component of the energy-momentum 4-vector $p^\mu=(E_p,\mathbf{p})$. But in this way the integrand is undefined, because the denominator is always 0. But it seems that in the contour integral, $E_p$ is just a fixed point in real axis, while the integral variable is $p^0$. How should I understand this?

Just rename $p_0$ to some other variable $q$, and stop worrying about what $q$ is physically..

I would add that $E_p = \sqrt{|p|^2+m^2}$ for a massive field, whereas $p^0$ cannot be expressed using $\textbf{p}$ or $m$.


I see such an expression:
$$
\frac{1}{2E_p}e^{-iE_p(x^0-y^0)}=-\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_Cdp^0\frac{e^{-ip^0(x^0-y^0)}}{(p^0-E_p)(p^0+E_p)}
$$
I know that this equation can be derived using Cauchy's integral formula. But I don't understand what it means by $p^0$ and $E_p$?

In your equation, $p^0$ is a dummy integration variable. It does not mean anything other than that.
In your equation, it would be less confusing to denote $E_p$ as $E_{\vec p}$ or $E_{|\vec p|}$ instead. The confusion arises because sometimes people write $p$ to mean $|\vec p|$, but sometimes people write $p$ to mean the relativistic four-momentum.

But in this way the integrand is undefined, because the denominator is always 0.

The denominator is not always zero. It only becomes zero when the dummy integration variable runs through $E_{\vec p}$ or $-E_{\vec p}$. If the integration contour avoids these two points the denominator is never zero.

How should I understand this?

In the usual sense of complex integration along a contour parametrized by the dummy variable $p^0$. You will often want to use Cauchy's theorem to perform such integrations.

So you mean that $E_\vec{p}$ is only the on-shell energy, i.e. $\sqrt{\mathbf{p}^2+m^2}$, while the $p^0$ is general energy (not necessarily on shell)?

I do mean that $E_{\vec p} = \sqrt{c^2|\vec p|^2 + c^4m^2}$. I do not mean that $p^0$ is anything other than a dummy integration variable. The notation $p^0$ is often used to denote the zeroth component of a four-momentum, but in your expression it is just the name of a dummy integration variable.

OK, I want to say it is the energy because in the context, the author want to write Feynman propagator as an integral over $p$ (4-dim), so I would rather give it a physical meaning

Ok, call it whatever you want, but it is still just a dummy integration variable. So, for example, if you had an integral like $\int dp^0 d^3p f(p^0, \vec p)$ both $p^0$ and $\vec p$ are just dummy integration variables regardless of what you call them.

Also, you seem to be getting confused when you call the dummy variable "energy," since, for example, you stated in your post that "the denominator is always 0," which is not true.
